# Escape regexp strings?

Tags: javascript, regex

I recall there was a way to have a very long string Regex escaped.

I think I used new Regexp but I can't recall how to do it.

Anyone here who knows how?

Comment: What is _a very long string Regex escaped_?

Comment: I'm guessing that there is a regex literal that is very long. The line  goes way off the page so @weng is wanting to split that up, seemingly for readbility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest you turn it into a string and then convert to a regex object using `new RegExp(`, as shown below:

```
var rxstr = "[\d]" + 
            "[\w]";
var rx = new RegExp(rxstr);
```

Or you could try (at the expense of formatting):

```
var x = "test";
var rxstr = "[\d]\
[\w]";
var rx = new RegExp(rxstr);
alert(rx);
```

The latter is faster as it does not create a number of new strings, but could be agued to be less readable.

Answer (score 8):

Your question is a little unclear. But if I understand you well, you need a way to escape the string in order to use it later in regular expressions.

PHP has a function `preg_quote` for this purpose. And there is a port of this function to JavaScript:

```
function preg_quote (str, delimiter) {
    // Quote regular expression characters plus an optional character  
    // 
    // version: 1107.2516
    // discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/preg_quote
    // +   original by: booeyOH
    // +   improved by: Ates Goral (http://magnetiq.com)
    // +   improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
    // +   bugfixed by: Onno Marsman
    // +   improved by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
    // *     example 1: preg_quote("$40");
    // *     returns 1: '\$40'
    // *     example 2: preg_quote("*RRRING* Hello?");
    // *     returns 2: '\*RRRING\* Hello\?'
    // *     example 3: preg_quote("\\.+*?[^]$(){}=!<>|:");
    // *     returns 3: '\\\.\+\*\?\[\^\]\$\(\)\{\}\=\!\<\>\|\:'
    return (str + '').replace(new RegExp('[.\\\\+*?\\[\\^\\]$(){}=!<>|:\\' + (delimiter || '') + '-]', 'g'), '\\$&');
}
```

*Original source:* http://phpjs.org/functions/preg_quote:491

Example of usage:

```
var strToMatch = "{test}??)(**test";
var subject = "Hello{test}??)(**testWorld";
var re = new RegExp( preg_quote(strToMatch) );

if ( subject.match(re) ) 
    document.write('TRUE');
else 
    document.write('FALSE');
```

Output:

```
TRUE
```

*A working example:* http://jsfiddle.net/37maV/

Comment: thanks, this is what i came here for. a shame that there is no builtin function RegExp.quote for this. i dont understand that delimiter part though. is there a char that sometimes is a RegExp special and sometimes not?

Comment: @peter delimiter part is present here because this function is a 1:1 port from PHP to JavaScript. There is no delimiter in JavaScript when a regular expression is created using a string. So I think the delimiter part in this function has no sense at all.

Answer (score 8):

## Short 'n Sweet (and Complete)

```
function escapeRegExp(str) {
  return str.replace(/[-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}

var re = new RegExp(escapeRegExp(str));
```

See: [Escape string for use in Javascript regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex/6969486#6969486)

Comment: not complete. where is `:`?

Comment: : is not a special regex character in javascript unless there's a ? in front, so escaping ? also prevents : from being special. Though please correct me if I'm mistaken. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: right. but then why do you have `]` escaped? escaping `[` would render it not-special either. same for `}` and `)`.

Comment: Hmmm... fair point.