# A regular expression that matches an arbitrary (user-provided) string

Tags: javascript, regex

Users will provide the string and I want to search that string through a list of predefined strings. The trick is that the user's string can be anything and may include regex characters like [*.?^ etc. So something like

```
"first half of my regex"   + `USER_STRING` +  "second half of my regex"
```

won't work. An obvious solution is to escape all special characters in `USER_STRING` with their escaped counterparts, but there's gotta be a better way.

PS: also, a simple string search won't do because I need to match patterns to the left and right of the string.

Comment: What better way would there be other than making the user string regex-safe?

Comment: Could you do it in two parts? First match your regex, then do the string search through the matches.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: I don't know why those answers escape `-`, though. It is not necessary to do so, when `[]` have been escaped.

Comment: @nhahtdh: True, but it doesn't hurt either. Some regex escape routines (for example Python's `re.escape()` simply escape *every* non-word character :)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has no built in regular expression escape function (analogous to PHP's `preg_quote`, for example).  Some people have taken it upon themselves to create an equivalent, though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6829401/454533

So no, there's not a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this function to make sure that all special characters are quoted and treated as literal character in regex:

```
function escapeRegex(input) {
    return input.replace(/[[\](){}?*+^$\\.|]/g, '\\$&');
}
```

The function expect a String as input and output a String with all the special characters escaped. This is meant to create a String that can be fed to the `RegExp` constructor to create a regex that matches the original string. Regarding whether the output of this method can be concatenated safely, check my additional note below.

List of [all special characters in JS regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) on MDN.

- Nothing much to say about these `^`, `$`, `.`, `|`, `*`, `?`, `+`.
  This also effectively disable the special meaning of `^` inside `[]` if the first character, and `?` inside `()` if the first character.
  The same for `?` and the lazy matching behavior when it follows a quantifier.
- `-` is only meaningful inside `[]` - but not any more when `[`, `]` are escaped.
  **There might be problem** if the template string is `"[" + input + "]"`. I don't emulate the behavior of `\Q` and `\E` inside character class here, but you can add `-` to the regex in the function above if you want to.
- `\` followed by some special sequence will lose its meaning when `\` is escaped.
  On a related note, the case that my method above fails is when the template string is `"\\" + input`. However, I would say ***the fault lies on whoever wrote the template string***, since this is total non-sense.
- `:`, `=`, `!` are only meaningful inside `()` (for non-capturing group and look-ahead) and must follow after `?`, but also lost its meaning when `(` and `)` are escaped. The `?` is already escaped so it poses no problem when the escaped string is inserted in between `()`.
  Without escaping those, the method above fails when the template string is `"(?" + input + ")"`. I again blame whoever who write this, since they are the one allowing the injection.
- `,` is only meaningful inside `{}`, but lost its meaning when `{` and `}` are escaped.
  **The case the escaping fails** is when you have the template string (e.g. to match a initializer) `"\\w+ = {" + input + "}"`, but normally, one will escape `{` and `}` in the template string if the intention is to match them as literal characters.
  There is also the case of repetition, but then, the template string should be `".{" + start + "," + end + "}`, and the input must be sanitized first.

In summary, the meta-characters in the template string must be properly escaped for any escaping function to work. If the escaped string is to be used in a character class, add `-` to the character class.