# Use regex to interpret different type of variable and do a find and replace with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

ok i have difficulty to understand the rejex and how it work, I try to do a basic dictionnary/glossary for a web site and i past too many time on it already.

There my code :

```
// MY MULTIPLE ARRAY
var myDictionnary = new Object();
myDictionnary.myDefinition = new Array();

myDictionnary.myDefinition.push({'term':"*1", 'definition':"My description here"});
myDictionnary.myDefinition.push({'term':"word", 'definition':"My description here"});
myDictionnary.myDefinition.push({'term':"my dog doesn't move", 'definition':"My description here"});

// MY FUNCTION
$.each(myDictionnary.myDefinition, function(){
    var myContent = $('#content_right').html();
    var myTerm = this.term;
    var myRegTerm = new RegExp(myTerm,'g');

    $('#content_right').html(myContent.replace(myRegTerm,'<span class="tooltip" title="'+this.definition+'"> *'+this.term+'</span>'));
});
```

I create my array and for each result i search in my div#content_right for the same content and replace it by span with title and tooltip. I put my regex empty to not confuse with what i have try before.

In my array 'term' you can see what kind of text i will research. It work for searching normal text like 'word'.

But for the regular expression like 'asterix' it bug, when i find a way to past it, he add it to text, i try many way to interpret my 'asterix' like a normal caracter but it doesn't work.

There what i want :
Interpret the variable literally whatever the text inside my var 'myTerm'. It this possible? if it not, what kind solution i shouldn use.

Thank in advance,
P.S. sorry for my poor english...(im french) 
Alex

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15004308/1400768

Comment: Please use `[]` and `{}` instead of `new Array()` and `new Object()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` is a special character in a Regex, meanining "0 or more of the previous character". Since it's the first character, it is invalid and you get an error.

Consider implementing [`preg_quote` from PHPJS](http://phpjs.org/functions/preg_quote/) to escape such special characters and make them valid for use in a regex.

---

HOWEVER, the way you are doing this is extremely bad. Not only because you're using `innerHTML` multiple times, but because what if you come across something like this?

`Blah blah blah <img src="blah/word/blah.png" />`

Your resulting output would be:

`Blah blah blah <img src="blah/<span class="tooltip" title="My description here"> *word</span>/blah.png" />`

The only real way to do what you're attempting is to specifically scan through the text nodes, then use `.splitText()` on the text node to extract the word match, then put that into its own `<span>` tag.

---

Here's an example implementation of the above explanation:

```
function definitions(rootnode) {
    if( !rootnode) rootnode = document.body;
    var dictionary = [
        {"term":"*1", "definition":"My description here"},
        {"term":"word", "definition":"My description here"},
        {"term":"my dog doesn't move", "definition":"My description here"}
    ], dl = dictionary.length, recurse = function(node) {
        var c = node.childNodes, cl = c.length, i, j, s, io;
        for( i=0; i<cl; i++) {
            if( c[i].nodeType == 1) { // ELEMENT NODE
                if( c[i].className.match(/\btooltip\b/)) continue;
                // ^ Exclude elements that are already tooltips
                recurse(c[i]);
                continue;
            }
            if( c[i].nodeType == 3) { // TEXT NODE
                for( j=0; j<dl; j++) {
                    if( (io = c[i].nodeValue.indexOf(dictionary[j].term)) > -1) {
                        c[i].splitText(io+dictionary[j].term.length);
                        c[i].splitText(io);
                        cl += 2; // we created two new nodes
                        i++; // go to next sibling, the matched word
                        s = document.createElement('span');
                        s.className = "tooltip";
                        s.title = dictionary[j].definition;
                        node.insertBefore(s,c[i]);
                        i++;
                        s.appendChild(c[i]); // place the text node inside the span
                        // Note that now when i++ it will point to the tail,
                        // so multiple matches in the same node are possible.
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
    recurse(rootnode);
}
```

Now you can call `definitions()` to replace all matches in the document, or something like `definitions(document.getElementById("myelement"))` to only replace matches in a certain container.

Comment: Thank you so much,

It work like charm now i will try to understand everything but your explanation give me a good idea. I see at some place it not a good practice to use innerHTML but i don't find another way (i know) to do it. I really need to better understand my javascript :P

Regards,
Alex

Comment: I recently got a problem, it seems it dont take all the elements, for exemple (it take the *CSST but not the *INT before and not the second *CSST) somoene know what can cause this problem. Beacause it work but in some case he dont get them all. If i change the place of the element (*LNT before *CSST) in my dictionnari, i get the *LNT but dont get the second *CSST.

And if i put my element into a (span) in my text, it take it without problem. But without the span it dont take it at all.

Answer (score 0):

By adding another variable, it will fix the problem:

```
            for( j=0; j<dl; j++) {
                  debutI =i;
                  if((io =c[i].nodeValue.indexOf(dictionary[j].term)) != -1) {
                        c[i].splitText(io+dictionary[j].term.length);
                        c[i].splitText(io);
                        cl += 2; // we created two new nodes
                        i++; // go to next sibling, the matched word
                        s = document.createElement('span');
                        s.className = "tooltip";
                        s.title = dictionary[j].definition;
                        node.insertBefore(s,c[i]);
                        i++;
                        s.appendChild(c[i]); // place the text node inside the span
                        // Note that now when i++ it will point to the tail,
                        // so multiple matches in the same node are possible.
                    }
                    i = debutI;
                }
```

Comme ça, on n'aura pas à mettre tous les spans partout dans le site à la main. >*_*>