# Check if word exists twice? (Regex)

Tags: javascript, regex

I am horrible at Regex, what i want is to check if a string has the word http twice, for example : `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/askhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask`, using the awesome feature of regex in javascript.

thanks.

Comment: Just use `indexOf`, duh

Comment: If you want to check whether a particular url occours twice, it's impossible to do it using pure regex. However, it should be easy to do using string ops.

Comment: /.*http.*http.*/ 0 or more character before first http, between the two https and after the last http

Comment: @shashwat: Occurring exactly twice can be done with regex, depending on how you do it, it can be beautiful or ugly...

Comment: @nhahtdh A little research tells me that you're right: Javascript can refer to matched groups within the expression, which will give us what we need. Theoretically however, regex can't do this, because one will need a PDA for this, and a FA won't be able to.

Comment: @shashwat: I think theoretical regex can do this (exactly n times), just that it is going to be ugly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
/http.*http/
```

Is the simplest expression that does this.  That is `http` anywhere in the string followed by zero or more characters followed by `http`.

Answer (score 5):

Although not exactly answering the question. Why not use indexOf() with offset, like so:

```
var offset = myString.indexOf(needle);
if(myString.indexOf(needle, offset)){
   // This means string occours more than one time
}
```

indexOf is quicker than regex. Also, it is a bit less exposed to special chars ruining the code.

Comment: I know i said regex in my question, but it was cuz i had no idea about 'indexOf', this is really helpful, thank youuuuu.

Comment: Can be done in a single line: `myString.indexOf(needle, myString.indexOf(needle) +1) > 0`.

Answer (score 3):

Another way, which can be extended to more than `n` times or exactly `n` times easily:

```
(inputString.match(/http/g) || []).length >= n
```

If you want to extend it to any literal string, you can use `RegExp` constructor with the input string after [regex-escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004172/a-regular-expression-that-matches-an-arbitrary-user-provided-string/15004308#15004308):

```
(inputString.match(new RegExp(escapeRegex(needle), 'g')) || []).length >= n
```

`escapeRegex` function replicated here for convenience:

```
function escapeRegex(input) {
    return input.replace(/[[\](){}?*+^$\\.|]/g, '\\$&');
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is exactly what i needed, cuz i said "twice" just to give a number, it could be 3 or more.

Comment: @user2463937: My answer was wrong, but no one actually comment... Just checked and fixed my answer.

Comment: Like the extended regex version but shouldn't the `[` and `^` be escaped in `escapeRegex` like this `/[\[\](){}?*+\^$\\.|]/g` so that it doesn't get misinterpreted in some regex engines (jslint throws a warning on these)?

Comment: @Xotic750: They don't need escaping. `^` only needs escaping if it is the first character in the character class. `[` doesn't actually needs escaping in JS (since there is no feature using `[` inside character class), but you can escape it if you like (since in other languages `[` may have special meaning inside character class).

Comment: Ok, then I guess it is jslint complaining needlessly (as normal), but escaping them should not hurt, just to silence jslint. :) and +1

Answer (score 3):

No need for a regex, you could use a little function like this that utilises [String.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and performs a word count.

EDIT: perhaps "word count" is a bad description and better would be "pattern matches"

Javascript

```
var testString = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/askhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask",
    testWord = "http";

function wc(string, word) {
    var length = typeof string === "string" && typeof word === "string" && word.length,
        loop = length,
        index = 0,
        count = 0;

    while (loop) {
        index = string.indexOf(word, index);
        if (index !== -1) {
            count += 1;
            index += length;
        } else {
            loop = false;
        }
    }

    return count;
}

console.log(wc(testString, testWord) > 1);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/FLgPT/)

Comment: yes good idea .... 39 lines of code instead of one ...

Comment: This example is fully functional, yours is not. This code is reusable, yours is not. This code counts all matches and return that value, yours does not. I'm not really concerned about line count, but I can count and you can not.

Comment: Yes but he asked about checking http twice ... not counting match ? in that case function wc(string, word) { return string.match(RegExp("("+word+")")).length } will do the trick too (still one line and fully reusable and also functional) :p

Comment: Quote from OP "Thanks a lot, that is exactly what i needed, cuz i said "twice" just to give a number, it could be 3 or more". The code you have now given was not as appeared in your answer. I could also make my function into a single line. The point was that I was giving an alternative to using a regex, which are known to behave differently across browsers (perhaps not in this case, but that is irrelevant). Your new code also misses `new` and it throws an error if no matches are found. So I thank you for your down vote and bid you farewell.

Comment: I hope you wont feel bad for this down vote ... I got one too for my answer ...

Comment: Yes you're right about the issue ... modify your answer then I'll up vote you again

Comment: Not at all, your new code is also missing the `g` flag. What are you expecting me to modify? `console.log(wc(testString, testWord) > 2)`;

Comment: well notice it's not a final answer, just a answer to your comment ;)

Comment: It is now modified so that logging displays `true` or `false`, `true` if more than 1

Answer (score 0):

```
// this code check if http exists twice
"qsdhttp://lldldlhttp:".match(/http.*http/);
```

Comment: Yes right, just modified it