# test method not working for regex for string starting with parantheses/special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to return boolean value for matching input string with a exact regex pattern but given code is not working as expected for string containing parentheses.Below is sample example of the same.

```
function myFunction() {
    var str = "Account Opening Member Onboarding Assignment Cube (AOMOA)";
    var patt = new RegExp("/\bAccount Opening Member Onboarding Assignment Cube (AOMOA)\b/");
    return patt.test(str);
}
```

Comment: escape the parantheses `\(` and `\)`. Otherwise they will be interpreted as capture group

Comment: @abhishekkannojia how do I do that at run time when any string is passed to function? rather more suitable question is how do I handle any special characters without affecting the matching process??

Comment: @rahulshukla Escape the strings before passing them in RegExp.

Comment: Just escaping a string won't solve the problem as it requires 1) whitespace word boundaries rather than `\b`, 2) syntax fix for the constructor notation, 3) only then escaping the literal pattern part. Thus, [Escape regexp strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828637/escape-regexp-strings) cannot be used as a duplicate reason (the accepted answer there is wrong, and it is by itself a dupe of [Is there a RegExp.escape function in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most probable that you look for whole words that are in between whitespaces, as the search phrases you are passing to the regex may start/end with special chars. In this case, use `(?:^|\s)` instead of the first `\b` and `(?!\S)` instead of the last `\b`.

Another point is that you need to [escape the search phrase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) for the eventual special chars to be treated as literal chars.

Use

```js
function myFunction(key) {
    var str = "Text with Account Opening Member Onboarding Assignment Cube (AOMOA) string inside";
    var patt = new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)" + key.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + "(?!\\S)");
    return patt.test(str);
}

var key="Account Opening Member Onboarding Assignment Cube (AOMOA)";
console.log(myFunction(key));
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you can explain this regular expression "(?:^|\\s)" ? @wiktor-stribiżew

Comment: The `(?:^|\s)` subpattern is a non-capturing group (`(?:....)`, used only to group subpatterns rather than store the submatches as additional parts of the resulting array) that contains two alternative branches: 1) `^`  that matches the start of the string, or (`|`) 2) `\s` that matches a whitespace. So the *key* will only get matched if it is preceded by a whitespace or start of string position. The `(?!\S)` is a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is no non-whitespace symbol after the *key* (so, there must be a whitespace or end of string).

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction(key) {
    var str = "Text with Account Opening Member Onboarding Assignment Cube (AOMOA) string inside";
    var patt = new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)" + key.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + "(?!\\S)");
    return patt.test(str);
}

var key="Account Opening Member Onboarding Assignment Cube (AOMOA)";
console.log(myFunction(key));
```